# general solution for double integral of square root of quadratic polynomials

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I wonder if there is a closed-form solution for double integral of square root of quadratic polynomials. Such as 
$$
\int _0 ^1 \int _0 ^1 \sqrt{a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot x \cdot y + d \cdot x+e\cdot y +1 } \ dx dy 
$$
I have tried to solve 
$$
 \int _0 ^1 \sqrt{a \cdot x^2 + b \cdot y^2 + c \cdot x \cdot y + d \cdot x+e\cdot y +1 } \ dx 
$$
and this has a closed form of solution, but is very complicated that makes it nearlly impossible to get the integral further on y.

So I wonder if a closed form solution really exists, does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Would it help to rotate in the $(x,y)$-plane to get rid of the $xy$-term, namely $cxy$? Then couldn’t you complete the square (shift the origin) to get your integrand to be something like $(a'\xi^2+b'\eta^2)^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: @Lubin thank you very much for your comment! But this only transforms the complexity from the polynomial to the domain and therefore does not simplify the final work.

Answer (score 1):

MAPLE got:

$\int _0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{a\cdot x^2+b\cdot y^2+c\cdot x\cdot y+d\cdot x+e\cdot y +1 }\ dx\ dy$

$$=\frac{1}{8}\left(-4\,ab\ln\left({\frac{c+d+2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+4\,ab\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+c+d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-4\,ae\ln\left({\frac{c+d+2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+4\,ae\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+c+d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+{c}^{2}\ln\left({\frac{c+d+2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-{c}^{2}\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+c+d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+2\,cd\ln\left({\frac{c+d+2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-2\,cd\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+c+d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-{d}^{2}\ln\left({\frac{d+2\,\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+{d}^{2}\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+d+2\,\sqrt{a+d+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+{d}^{2}\ln\left({\frac{c+d+2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-{d}^{2}\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+c+d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+4\,a\ln\left({\frac{d+2\,\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-4\,a\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+d+2\,\sqrt{a+d+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)-4\,a\ln\left({\frac{c+d+2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+4\,a\ln\left({\frac{2\,a+c+d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}}\right)+4\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}{a}^{3/2}-4\,\sqrt{a+d+1}{a}^{3/2}+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}c-2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}c+2\,\sqrt{a}d+2\,\sqrt{a+b+c+d+e+1}\sqrt{a}d-2\,\sqrt{b+e+1}\sqrt{a}d-2\,\sqrt{a+d+1}\sqrt{a}d\right){a}^{-3/2}$$